# Why is there a NameError: name [variable] is not defined in this list variable?

Tags: python

I get this error whenever I try to run my code. I believe both the lists's `summary_name` and `summary` lists are not working.

Error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Asus/Google Drive/Sun Gleam & Fine Works/System Improvement/Accounting/Voucher Reports/Voucher Reports", line 12, in <module>
    summary_name[i] = data_listofaccounts['Account Name']
NameError: name 'summary_name' is not defined
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

entries_csv = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\Entries.csv"
listofaccounts_csv = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\List of Accounts.csv"

data_entries = pd.read_csv(entries_csv)
data_listofaccounts = pd.read_csv(listofaccounts_csv)

i = 0
for account_name in data_listofaccounts['Account Name']:
    summary_name[i] = data_listofaccounts['Account Name']
    for debit_account in data_entries['DEBIT ACCOUNT']:
        if account_name == debit_account:
            summary[i] += data_entries['DEBIT AMOUNT']
    i += 1

for p in range(i):
    print(summary[p])
    print(summary_name[p])
```

Comment: What list? You never made a list.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm a beginner to python. Isn't `summary[i]` and `summary_name[i]` supposed to make a list? Do I have to declare lists? Because normal variables do not need declaration such as `data_entries` and `data_listofaccounts`

Comment: Well, I think you need to define it first. Like summary_name=[None]*100 or summary_name={} (dictionary)

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus so do I do `summary[i]=0` prior to `summary[i] += data_entries['DEBIT AMOUNT']`?

Comment: You need summary_name=[None]*100 or [0]*100 or [anyhing]*any int or a dictionary

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus Right that works. I don't understand why you have to do this though why don't they just allow a 0 to initialize the list

Comment: Please do the reading I provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
summary_name[i]
```

assumes that there already is something that has the name `summary_name` and that allows access using `[i]`. Since Python  is a dynamic language, this can be anything. All that is necessary to use `[i]` on an object is to implement [`object.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for reading and [`object.__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) for writing. How is Python supposed to know which of the many classes that do this you want `summary_name` to be an instance of?

So you first have to define `summary_name`, for example as an empty list

```
summary_name = ["I", "am", "a", "list"]
```

a tuple

```
summary_name = ("I", "am", "a", "tuple")
```

or a string

```
summary_name = "I am a string."
```

All these allow *read* access using `summary_name[i]`.

Since you want to use *write* access, you must define an object that allows `summary_name[i] = something`. A list with 100 entries, all initialized to `None` could be created using

```
summary_name = [None] * 100
```

Only after this can you set entries of this list.